# Why was my query closed?

Tags: discussion

I asked a perfectly reasonable and relevant question earlier today. Or at least, tried to.

[How do I fully save a modern webpage using javascript (eg facebook), in its intended viewable formatting, for fully offline viewing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1762065/how-do-i-fully-save-a-modern-webpage-using-javascript-eg-facebook-in-its-inte)

Within minutes, it had been closed by someone. No explanation given other than 'off topic as not related to hardware or software'. How on earth anyone came to that conclusion is beyond me - the question boils down to quite literally asking how to use software (web browser) to archive a certain type of data (webpages).

I've flagged it now twice for review, referencing similar questions that WERE allowed, and they've dismissed...due to supposedly providing 'no evidence' - which is even more at odds with reality.

Who is making these decisions? They're so bizzare they honestly feel deliberately spiteful, goodness knows why, I've barely just joined.

Comment: "I've flagged it now twice for review, referencing similar questions that WERE allowed, and they've dismissed...due to supposedly providing 'no evidence' - which is even more at odds with reality." - While you might have flagged it twice, only the most recent revision, made it reviewable. It has yet to be reviewed.  You have to wait until it's reviewed in the queue of contributions to be reopened.

Comment: It's only been 8 hours since the question was closed. You have also received zero downvotes on any of your contributions. This comment is a repost of a previous comment reduced to the absolute minimum

Answer (score 3):

> How on earth anyone came to that conclusion is beyond me

I *think* this is a misunderstanding based on poor word choice in the question *title*.  If people were to read it more closely and read the question *body*, I *think* they would realize that this wasn't a *programming* question.  Once I get past the poor word choice, it looks to me to be on-topic here since you are asking a desktop-browser *capability*.

The title of your question was:

> How do I fully save a modern webpage using javascript (eg facebook) ...

The problem here is *"using javascript"* -- It makes it sound like you *want to use JavaScript to save the webpage* if someone is reading too quickly.  That would be a programming question.

However, it's clear from the example you give (Facebook), and the description "a modern webpage", along with the explanation in the body that what you really mean is:

> How do I fully save a modern webpage *which uses* JavaScript (e.g. Facebook)

You don't want to do this programmatically, but you are looking for some equivalent to the *Save complete webpage* option that will capture JavaScript-generated content and formatting as well.

Apparently the moderator on Stack Overflow who rejected the migration *did* realize this, which leaves the question in limbo currently.

I've edited the question title and voted-to-reopen it here on SU.